# Deploying Flask App to AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am attempting to deploy a simple "Hello World!" Flask application through AWS Elastic Beanstalk using its web console.

While creating the environment, "Events" section of AWS EB mentions the following two errors :

1. Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.
2. Create environment operation is complete, but with errors. For more information, see troubleshooting documentation.

The 'eb-engine.log' mentions one error which is :

```
[ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [StageApplication]. Stop running the command. Error: chown /var/app/staging/env/bin/python: no such file or directory
```

What I tried to fix the issue :

1. Checked env/bin file to locate python. Found the python file.

My file path :

```
myapp
----env
    --bin  //only mentioning the python files
      --python
      --python3
      --python3.9
----static
----templates
.gitignore
application.py
requirements.txt
```

application.py :

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for
application = app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index(): 
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

requirements.txt :

```
click==8.0.4
Flask==2.0.3
greenlet==1.1.2
itsdangerous==2.1.1
Jinja2==3.0.3
MarkupSafe==2.1.1
Werkzeug==2.0.3
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your virtual environment named `env` is conflicting with the one that Elastic Beanstalk creates on the server instance.

To fix this, make sure your `.gitignore` file contains an entry for `env/` to exclude your virtual environment directory from being deployed in your source bundle. Alternatively, use an `.ebignore` file.

For more information on using `.ebignore` (or `.gitignore`), see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-flask.html#python-flask-deploy and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-configuration.html#eb-cli3-ebignore.